# problem with skeleton markers in pi-robot-ros-pkg with kinect

Tags: ros, skeleton-tracker, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:

Has anyone used the above package with ROS? I ran roslaunch skeleton_markers markers_from_tf.launch which tracks using the openni_tracker and set my rviz config to markers_from_tf.vcg. If I use a fixed frame relative to one of the body points, say head or torso, I see the markers but not always all of them. It's like rviz shifted the image seen on the screen down or maybe its a zoom..

Anyway if I set fixed frame to the camera, ie. skeleton_openni_depth_frame, then I don't see the markers any-more. If I come real close to the camera I see the markers but they are all jumbled up and don't make any sense. Could there be a problem with the transform from the camera to the 2d representation?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11742/problem-with-skeleton-markers-in-pi-robot-ros-pkg-with-kinect/) by [asrinivasan31](https://answers.ros.org/users/1262/asrinivasan31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wrote the [skeleton_markers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/skeleton_markers) package and just now found some issues in the markers_from_tf.vcg RViz config file that must have crept in when I went from Diamondback to Electric.  Can you try an "svn update" and see if that fixes the problem for you?  Also, are you using Diamondback or Electric?

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asrinivasan31](https://answers.ros.org/users/1262/asrinivasan31/) on 2011-11-01**:
Thank you for looking into this. I am running ros-electric. I don't have the kinect with me right now, but I'll try it as soon as I can and let you know.